# Django >> contrib/auth/models.py >> Templates ? Ar these the only templates >> django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets

Tags: django, django-registration

I have been searching for a while - my usecase is simple and common. 
Have to use "django_registration-redux" to give users a Register link . 
Format the HTML template enough , to make it presentable .

The register form is being provided by - `class AbstractUser` within the file = `django/contrib/auth/models.py` .

The templates being used are from DIR `django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets` . 
Adding anything in here - say i add some HTML to the file `input.html` , does not give the desired results .

Also adding formatted html within the file `django/contrib/auth/models.py` , in the `class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):` , also doesnt give desired results.
I tried adding - 
`help_text = format_html('<div style="color:grey;"> {} <strong><b>{}</b></strong> {}</div>', 'Username is a Required Field. Your UserName for' , 'DigitalCognition', 'can have max - 150 characters. You may use Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.')`.

Finally my Question - Where to find the base.html or any kind of scaffolding templates for these widgets , i understand tinkering with these widgets is incorrect , thanks

My current Registration Page looks like the pic inserted here -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My mistake i seem to have forgotten that the templates i need to tweak are here - 
`/.../python3.6/site-packages/registration/templates/registration/registration_form.html`.

Kindly ignore my silly question - i have a bad habit to go on chasing red herrings.

Answering the query from Frank in the comment below - 
The settings.py has a templates directive `'APP_DIRS': True,`.

This shall guide Django to seek the registration templates in the APP_DIR for INSTALLED_APPS `'registration'`.

Further read here - https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: How comes it to that place?

Comment: @Frank - have edited my answer , hope this is what you were asking ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.contrib.auth import forms


class SignupView(FormView):
    """view for signing up new users"""
    form_class = forms.UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'user/signup.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        new_user = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            )
        login(self.request, new_user)
        return FormView.form_valid(self, form)
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <main>
    <form id="signupform" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <table>
        {{form.as_table}}
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

The default table output doesn't include to hide the hints. Therefore i made few css changes.

```css
#signupform input{
    width:100%;
}
.helptext {
    display: none;
}

.errorlist{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```